# Is the infinite-dimensional simplex convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, simplex

Let

$$S = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{\mathbb{N}^+} \mid \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i = 1 \right\}$$

Is $S$ convex?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if $S$ is convex?  Local convexity is a property of a topological vector space, and $S$ is not a vector space.

Comment: @Aweygan thank you, yes convex.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? It seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: This true both if you interprete $\Sigma$ as sum or as series

Comment: Is your difficulty with not knowing what the definition of convexity for subsets of $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{\mathbb{Z}_+}$? (That would be my difficulty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of a convex set:  a subset $A$ of a real or complex vector space $V$ is said to be *convex* if for every $x,y\in A$ and every $\lambda\in[0,1]$ we have $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in A$ or equivalently if for every $\lambda\in[0,1]$ we have $\lambda A+(1-\lambda)A\subset A$.  In this problem, the vector space is $\mathbb R^{\mathbb Z_+}$ of all real sequences.

Given $x=\{x_n\}$ and $y=\{y_n\}$ in $S$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$, we have 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lambda x_n+(1-\lambda)y_n
=\lambda\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n+(1-\lambda)\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n=\lambda+(1-\lambda)=1$$
(convergence is a non-issue). Hence $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in S$, and $S$ is convex.

Comment: If this is not clarifying enough, let me know.

Comment: Probably explaining what you mean by being a non-issue would be helpful. You showed that something is in S, but to be there the series has to at least make sense.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez why the series shouldn't make sense? If the series $x=\{x_n\}$ belongs to $S$, it is 1.

Comment: The first series you wrote is built out of two other series.